# What is the difference between middle ware function and a normal function

Tags: node.js, middleware

As I know that a piece of code in the application is a middle ware then what is the difference between middle ware and normal function in nodejs

Comment: middleware architecture is a bunch of functions 
https://www.packtpub.com/mapt/book/web-development/9781783287338/1/ch01lvl1sec13/exploring-middleware-architecture

technically it is just function, there is no difference between middle ware and normal function(middleware have next() call), it's just some architecture pattern